# <select> 100% width with inline text

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I have filtering dropdowns on a page that I need to "display: inline". There's a h2, label, select. My problem is that if I set them all to display: inline, the select shows up on top of the select because the width is set to 100% (somewhere in Foundation 4). I want the select to use 100% of the space left over inside of the container element. I'm missing something...

```
<div class="blog-filter-selection">
<div class="row">
<h2 class="large-3 small-12 columns">Filter By:</h2>
<div class="topic-filter large-4 small-12 columns">
<label>Topic:</label>
<select onchange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" name="tag-dropdown">
<div class="company-filter large-5 small-12 columns">
<label></label>
<select></select>
</div></div>
```

So, how do I set the select to be 100% of the space left over inside of the div.topic-filter?

SASS

```
div.blog-filter-selection{

h2{
    color: $primary-color; 
    font-weight: 600; 
    font-size: emCalc(24);
    display: inline;
}
div.topic-filter, div.company-filter{
    display: inline;
}
div.topic-filter label, div.company-filter label{
    font-size: emCalc(16);
    font-family: $header-font-family;
    font-weight: $header-font-weight;
    float: left;
}
div.topic-filter select, div.company-filter select{
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;

}
}
```

Browser Result
[image]

Comment: I don't think I understand what your trying to do. You want the select tags to be in the same place that they are now but to just take up more space?

Comment: @ddelnanao I want "Topic" to be next to (on the left) select, and have the select take up the remainder of the space inside the container div. I don't want to specify a percentage or a px value as its a responsive design.